# How can I create a one time download link with Amazon S3?

Tags: php, jquery, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a one time download link to an amazon s3 hosted file. This link expires once the file has been downloaded.

I want this file to still be hosted but a visitor can only download the file once.

The scenario I need this for is: I have a file download website where users pay for a file. I want the user to only be able to download the file once from the website (and Amazon s3), I also do not want the user to be able to share a direct download link with other people.

If this isn't possible I wonder if it is more efficient to limit it by an IP address or Cookie if possible?

Comment: I will suggest you to to host your file on an self hosted website and handle download with an server-side scripting language like php

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no way to tell S3 to allow a link to be used only once. But you can create a link that can only be used until a specified time. What I do is redirect the requester to an S3 link that expires in a few minutes, so he or she doesn't have time to share it. You can make that expiration time very short, even a few seconds, so long as their browser has time to receive the redirect response and follow it.

Comment: This sounds appropriate to my sitatuion any information on how to go about this?

Comment: I see you are using PHP. I don't program in that, but Amazon has an SDK for it, and it looks like the createPresignedUrl method is what you should use. It's documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createPresignedUrl

Comment: So your web page would include a link to a URL at your site. Clicking that URL would cause your site to send a redirect response to the pre-signed URL you create just then, to expire in a minute or so.

Comment: For your case, even better than the more general createPresignedUrl method is the getObjectUrl method: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl. $s3->getObjectUrl('bucket-name', 'object-key', '+5 minutes');

Comment: If I have a link expire in 5 minutes and it takes longer than 5 minutes to download the file, will the download be cancelled? Does the expiration time only apply to the start of the download?

Comment: I'm almost positive it applies to the start of the download, as that's when the authentication happens. But you could create a test pretty easily if the answer's important to you.

Comment: @CharlesEngelke, you're right, `CloudFront checks the expiration date and time in a signed URL at the time of the HTTP request. If a client begins to download a large object immediately before the expiration time, the download should complete even if the expiration time passes during the download. If the TCP connection drops and the client tries to restart the download after the expiration time passes, the download will fail.` From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html

Same should apply for S3

Comment: There is an ugly workaroud... give the download link, then rename the file in S3 to a uuid for the next download... ugly if a lot of users try to download at the sdame time but helpful if you have small qty of users that can wait you rename before downloading.
May be the renaming can be done using a lambda after reading the s3 event of download... not done this but may be a way.

Answer (score 7):

You can write an "one time url generator" service (either in form of website or rest API) and make use of aws federated user feature to achieve this.

Consider the following procedure:

- When user wants a one time url, they send the request to your "one
  time url generator" service.
- The your service generates a "one time url" and returns it to the user. The url is a one-to-one mapping to the S3 resource the user wants.
- When the user makes a requests to the "one time url", the service creates a temporary user using the AWS federated user feature, and generates an S3 presigned url on behalf of the temporary user.
- The service sends the response back to the user, redirecting to the presigned url.
- The user follows the redirection, and starts downloading the file.
- The service then deletes the temporary user. (Or lets it expire.)

Comment: Any open-source projects have this functionality ?

Comment: @AviParshan is there any similar Java libraries?

Comment: @sinu I don't know of any