# How to use presigned URL to upload file in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, cdn, pre-signed-url

In `Amazan S3` and many open source CDN servers like `Minio` there is a feature called `presigned URL` to let users without credential information to download/upload files. but there is a small problem in **uploading** file. the General scenario is:

1. we pass presigned URL to client
2. client upload files to Amazon s3
3. client inform the server that file has been uploaded.

But after that, client can upload files and overwrite them until expiration time of presigned URL. So we can not trust any file in the S3 server until URL got expired. It's not desirable!

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467460/how-can-i-create-a-one-time-download-link-with-amazon-s3 - in short, you can't without something else in between.

Comment: so what is the benefit of Presigned upload URL? if we want to trust the sender, we could even give him the secret!